# Display Custom WooCommerce Product tab with ACF repeater fields if subfields exists

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom snippet to display a custom tab on the product page. The content is ACF file fields with repeater field.
It works fine, when I set the files for the product, they all appear on the product page the way I want them to.
I would like that if no file is specified, the tab should not appear either.

Here is the code I use:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woostify_custom_tab' );
function woostify_custom_tab( $tabs ) {
    if( get_field('letoltheto_katalogusok')  ) {
        $tabs['tab-catalogues'] = array(
            'title'    => 'Letölthető katalógus',
            'callback' => 'woostify_custom_tab_content',
            'priority' => 25,
        );
    }
    return $tabs;
}

function woostify_custom_tab_content( $slug, $tab ) {
    if (have_rows('letoltheto_katalogusok')) {
        while (have_rows('letoltheto_katalogusok')) {
            the_row();
            $file = get_sub_field('letoltheto_katalogus');
            $file2 = get_sub_field('letoltheto_katalogusa');
            $file3 = get_sub_field('letoltheto_katalogusb');
            ?>
            <br>      
            <div class="katalogusok">
            <a href="<?php echo $file['url']; ?>" target="_blank" ><?php echo $file['filename']; ?></a>
            <a href="<?php echo $file2['url']; ?>" target="_blank" ><?php echo $file2['filename']; ?></a>
            <a href="<?php echo $file3['url']; ?>" target="_blank" ><?php echo $file3['filename']; ?></a>
            </div>
            <?php 
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Wrap the adding of the tab into `if (have_rows('letoltheto_katalogusok')) { ... }` as well?

Comment: (Wrapping the while loop into that if condition is superfluous to begin with. `while (have_rows('letoltheto_katalogusok'))` - if this call here does not return true to begin with, then the while loop will not iterate even one single time either.)

Answer (score 1):

Do the same thing with the part that adds the tab, as you did in the code that is supposed to actually fill the tab - use `have_rows('letoltheto_katalogusok')` to check if the repeater actually contains anything to loop over.

```
function woostify_custom_tab( $tabs ) {
    if( have_rows('letoltheto_katalogusok') ) {
        $tabs['tab-catalogues'] = array(
            'title'    => 'Letölthető katalógus',
            'callback' => 'woostify_custom_tab_content',
            'priority' => 25,
        );
    }
    return $tabs;
}
```

Note that `have_rows` is "dynamic", it will return false once all rows have been iterated over (that's why it can terminate the `while` loop, once all rows have been output.) But since at this point you are *not* iterating over the rows, it will still hold the same initial true or false value, when it gets to your loop in the `woostify_custom_tab_content` function.

Comment: Thank you, but still not working. It works like my version did before. If I delete the PDF files, they don't appear, but the "letölthető katalógusok" tab remains.

Comment: Did you delete the actual files, or did you remove the ACF repeater entries?

Comment: I deleted the assigned PDF files from the product page.